# Can sombody explain me this arrow function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, arrow-functions

here is the code:

```
const createI18n = (config) => ({
    locale: ref(config.locale),
    messages: config.messages,
    $t(key) {
        return this.messages[this.locale.value][key]
    },
})
```

Is `locale` an object or a proprety of object?

I'm kind of new in javascript and i really struggling in understanding this arrow function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better understand what is going on here, you could take a look at a normal function equivalent:

```
    function createI18n(config){
        return {
           locale: ref(config.locale),
           messages: config.messages,
           $t(key) {
              return this.messages[this.locale.value][key]
           }
        }
}
```

So basically you are returning an object from that arrow function.
You are also using a shorthand version of an arrow function, which omitts the return keyword.

So those two are equivalent to the one above as well

```
const createI18n = (config) => ({
    locale: ref(config.locale),
    messages: config.messages,
    $t(key) {
        return this.messages[this.locale.value][key]
    },
})

const createI18n = (config) => {
/* you could do some operations here, but not in the shorthand version */
return {
    locale: ref(config.locale),
    messages: config.messages,
    $t(key) {
        return this.messages[this.locale.value][key]
    },
  }
}
```

It is just a more convenient kind to write the function.

update:
The result object would look like this:

```
{
 locale: //some value,
 messages: //some other value,
 $t: // function
}
```

update 2:
you could rewrite your function to observe the result in the console.

```
const createI18n = (config) => {
const result = {
     locale: ref(config.locale),
     messages: config.messages,
     $t(key) {
         return this.messages[this.locale.value][key]
     },
 }
 console.log(result);
 return result
}
```

Comment: Is $t(key) a method of this returned object?

Comment: yes, see my updated answer. Also you could try to observe the result in the console, to find out what exactly the properties are. I will add how to do so in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with arrow functions.

`locale` is the name of a property of an object.

The value of that property is another object (which has a property named `value` on it).